# .htaccess rewrite for SEF URLs that works at 1&1 but not other hosts

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been researching and trying everything i can get my hands on but this strangeness persists.

I have an understandably odd rewrite scenario where a php script that does image resizing and caching is being called without its .php extension to create a SEF url, the odd part is that i'm passing all the 'parameters' as if they were a subdirectory of the script and in this scenario my rewrite fails, ie:

```
http://10.3.2.218/libraries/imageresize/images/portfolio/200/test.jpg
```

In the above url, 'imageresize' is in reality 'imageresize.php' and everything after that is captured by my script using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and processed down to image location and dimensions. the output of the script is a processed image with the needed content type etc.

The exact issue is that my rewrite rules work well under normal conditions and they work well (with above scenario) at 1and1 where my client is, but not on my development centos webserver/vm or my VPS with cpanel. It would seem that anywhere but 1and1 apache is maybe assuming /imageresize/ is a directory and never testing to see if its a script. My rewrite rules are as follows.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

I guess i'm either looking for a solution related to the server configuration or help with a better rewrite rule or at the very least an explanation why something actually works at 1and1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) in enabled on the servers that don't work.

Change

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

to

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
```